# Do SHA-1 certs work with TLS 1.2?

Tags: tls, certificates

I have been looking at potentially disabling the use of all SSL versions, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 across all servers in my environment. However, I have an internal CA that issues SHA-1 based digitally signed certs for internal use only.

Is there a potential for impact on the certs if SSL is disabled please? or can SHA-1 signed certs support TLS 1.2?

Comment: I believe the hash function used as part of the certificate's RSA signature is independent of the TLS version or cipher suite. I don't know where to look for a reference, but I think you should be fine.

Comment: Mike: not entirely. **TLS1.3** (RFC 8446 4.4.2.2) allows SHA1-signed server certs only as a last resort, and only if permitted by the client -- in sigalgs or sigalgs_cert extension, per the paragraph about 'legacy' in 4.2.3. And since there are no longer any sigalgs codes for MD5, and sigalgs is now mandatory (except for PSK), MD5 signatures can't be used at all. For 1.2 sigalgs _can_ prohibit SHA1, or MD5, but it is the program's or user's option. Below 1.2 there is free choice.

Comment: OP: so check if your clients are specifying a sigalgs extension with SHA1(+whatever) in it.

Answer (score 3):

TLS 1.2 supports certificates using SHA-1, as described kind of cryptically in [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246):

```
   -  Any certificates provided by the client MUST be signed using a
      hash/signature algorithm pair found in
      supported_signature_algorithms.

   ...

   enum{
       none(0), md5(1), sha1(2), sha224(3), sha256(4), sha384(5),
       sha512(6), (255)
   } HashAlgorithm;
```

Certificates signed with SHA-1 are [not trusted in modern browsers](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html), but switching TLS versions does not change that.